# How do researchers know that a species is at risk of extinction?

Tags: extinction

> Recently researchers present evidence that the platypus is at risk of extinction.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_in_science)

How do researchers know that a species is at risk of extinction?  I mean Earth is so large, said species could be deep in the Pacific ocean or somewhere else that has been thoroughly explored.

Comment: Habitat. (most) species can't live under your bed.

Comment: I can give some leads to those who can write a good answer: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/23311481_Quantification_of_Extinction_Risk_IUCN's_System_for_Classifying_Threatened_Species and https://www.iucnredlist.org/about/barometer-of-life and https://www.google.com/search?q=measurement+of+extinction+risk&oq=measurement+of+extinction+risk&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l4.3520j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, questions need to be narrowly focuses so that they are answerable on this site. This would need a book to answer in a non-trivial manner since different species have different requirements. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

The to assess the extinction risk of a species, Researchers first study the ecology and global populations of the species.

Then mathematical models are applied to  simulate the population dynamics and estimate extinction risk.

The results are collected in the IUCNs Red list.

https://www.iucnredlist.org/